# Browser JavaScript mousedown event: To detect right mouse button: Do I look at "button" or "which"?

Tags: javascript, html, web

In the (good?) old days jQuery normalized `which` to 1, 2, and 3 for left, middle and right mouse buttons respectively.

The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) indicates that `button` is standard, producing values of 0, 1, and 2.

On the desktop, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE11, and Edge all provide both `button` and `which`, so either one seems like will work.

(I am writing raw JS by the way. No JS library dependencies. I'm listening for `mousedown` using `element.addEventListener()`)

Which one is the one that we want to use moving forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which one is the one that we want to use moving forward?

Well, the specs tells about the `button` property, but `which`.

So this should answer the question, but you can use `which` as long as it is supported by the browsers independently from W3C specs.

Scott showed that `bitmap` of 1, 2, 4

Which is also in the current spec under `buttons`

> The buttons being pressed when the mouse event was fired: Left button=1, Right button=2, Middle (wheel) button=4, 4th button (typically, "Browser Back" button)=8, 5th button (typically, "Browser Forward" button)=16. If two or more buttons are pressed, returns the logical sum of the values. E.g., if Left button and Right button are pressed, returns 3 (=1 | 2).

Maybe interesting for some drawing applications, with multiple gestures types..

Comment: Indeed. Excellent. `buttons` on that page was very close to catching my eye but I glossed over it. This is really useful.

Comment: @StevenLu I came to it, because of your question & link, learning by helping, awesome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Going forward use zero based.

```
0 - left mouse button
1 - middle mouse button
2 - right mouse button
```

Older browsers (IE 8 and below, hopefully you don't have to support them) were:

```
1 - left
4 - middle
2 - right
```

Some sample code to test this with.

```
<script>
        var clickTest = document.getElementById('clickTest');
        clickTest.addEventListener('mousedown', clickHandler);

        function clickHandler(event) {
            alert(event.button);
        }
</script>

<p id="clickTest">This is a test</p>
```

Comment: Yeah I dunno. It is useful to have this be a bitmap (as 1,2,4 indicates it would be) but that seems unsupported

Comment: @StevenLu check out the specs under buttons or read my answer